# Can a 1 second long brown out harm my PC/electronics?

Tags: undervolting

Ever since the summer all around the town im in PA since its so hot the power has been going off and sometimes it has been a quick brown out like half a second i would say my lamp turns brown and fan goes slow for a sec and my pc does not turn off or monitor and they seem fine it has happened twice already and im getting worried if there is any possibility this will cause harm in the future to my PC or out electrical equipment .. My house is perfectly wired and stuff its acutally something happening around my town so theres nothing i can really do about it and i just wanted to see if i can find an answer here .. thanks for your time if you read this and take the time to answer take care

Comment: Can? Yes. Is it likely? No. If you want to be safe, buy an UPS.

Comment: I imagine it depends on what the "normal" voltage is? Because if you're in a 230V area, and the voltage dips down to 110V, that's still within "normal" range for lots of PSUs...

Answer (score 1):

The brown out itself is unlikely to damage your hardware but could damage/corrupt data if you are very unlucky.

Taking a "bigger picture though", if you are having brownouts you may well be having voltage spikes as well - these can damage your hardware.

It might be worth putting your equipment behind a UPS (even a cheap one whose battery is not very good - you are after the surge protection almost all UPS's will have built in and bonus if it can keep your equipment running for 10 seconds) or even a simple surge suppressor.  Some better power strips even have these built in.